# Troubles using Cask on Emacs

Tags: emacs

I am trying to using the combination [Cask](http://cask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/introduction.html)+[Pallet](https://github.com/rdallasgray/pallet) to manage my packages in emacs.

I have created a `Cask` file in my `.emacs.d` directory with the following:

```
(source melpa)

(depends-on "pallet")
```

And I have the following `init.el` lines

```
(require 'cask "~/.cask/cask.el")
(cask-initialize)
(require 'pallet)
(pallet-mode t)
```

I have run `cask install` inside `.emacs.d`directory and, by doing this, have  created a package directory under .emacs.d/.cask/,  and pallet seems to have been successfully included under this directory.

When I initialise emacs, however, it is failing to found the `pallet` package and is throwing:

```
File error: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, pallet
```

I am on MacOXS and using emacs 25.1. Does anyone does have any thought about what might be the problem.

Comment: This is a total shot in the dark but have you checked the subfolders of your `~/.emacs.d/.cask` directory? There should be one matching your Emacs version. If there is not, that would be one reason for that error.

I had a problem with that because I was (unknowingly) using two Emacs versions, one from an application bundle and one "from the system" somewhere and the latter one produced exactly your error.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your opinion @JulianKniephoff! But ,unfortunately, it is not it... There is only one subfolder in my "~/.emacs.d/.cask" directory and it is named with the correct version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My system is macOS Sierra 10.12.3, Emacs 25.1.50.1 and cask 0.7.6.
I've had same issue as you. Below is my Cask file.

```
(source melpa-stable)
(source gnu)
(depends-on "pallet")
(depends-on "req-package")
```

After I have upgraded my cask version from 0.7.6 to 0.8.1 the issue has been solved.

Comment: upgrading cask version helped! Thanks!